# Does the Grand Inquisitor's choice at the end of season 1 impact 'Shroud of Darkness'?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels

At first I wondered if all Jedi turned to the dark side would revert back to their Force-loving selves when they die, but that didn't seem to make sense... There could be potentially thousands of them over the millennia.

> So then I wondered, why the Inquisitor? Why the second chance to serve in the Temple?

Does this have anything to do with the final choice he made in 'Fire Across the Galaxy' to...

> let go of the bridge and not force Kanan to loose the killing stroke on a former Jedi? Does it have something to do with admitting his fear and then submitting himself as a sacrifice instead of continuing to serve the Emperor? Did that final choice redeem him to the Force?

Comment: @SJuan76 Yes, I understand your point of view. I guess I am trying to view the scene in an optimistic way. So then, no, his last act is not the thing that gives him a shot at serving in the Jedi Temple again?

Answer (score 2):

No, the Grand Inquisitor did not turn back to the light in the Season 1 finale. Rather, he gave into fear.

> "There are some things far more frightening than death." **- Grand Inquisitor**

He chose to die rather than face punishment from Vader.

In *Shroud of Darkness*, the Grand Inquisitor is just a manifestation of the Force (an illusion) either created by Yoda or the Force itself a la the Dagabah cave. This was Kanan's trial to become a Jedi Knight. Kanan had to come to the understanding that he could not control Ezra's future with violence (via protecting Ezra) and the that Ezra turning to the Dark Side was a dangerous possibility. Kanan seeing that the Grand Inquisitor was once a Jedi Temple guardian further reinforces this idea.

Comment: would love to see the proof / justification that Kanan's vision was manifested specifically by Yoda.

Comment: @NKCampbell I could add a justification to my answer, but I don't think it would improve my answer as the main point of that sentence is that it was not the real Grand Inquisitor that Kanan was confronting. An alternative explanation would be that the Force itself manifested the illusion, but the Force itself has no reason to confer Knighthood to a Padawan (because Knighthood is a Jedi concept, not a universal one). That is something we only see the Jedi Council do (or Jedi Knights/Masters with the power invested in them by the Council).

Comment: I think it's a good edit and I agree with the logic there. I also agreed w/ the thought that he did not turn to good at the end. I wonder if the Temple was  crafted or tinkered with in some way as to enable that sort of thing to occurr - much like how Ezra was given his crystal in the temple. I don't think Yoda teleported one to him. It seems like the temple is able to act on behalf of the Jedi

Comment: @NKCampbell I believe illusions/visions can probably be induced anywhere that is strong with the Force and I imagine a Jedi temple would still be strong with the Force. As for the lightsaber crystal, I would speculate that a lightsaber crystal was left behind in the temple and the Force allowed Ezra to find it (or it brought it to him). The temples were probably designed to encourage stuff like this because I imagine that Padawans would have to be tested in various ways.

Comment: @ncalmbeblpaicr0011 So there is no redemption for the Grand Inquisitor. It is an illusion; a lesson/test for Kanan and a warning that it is a very real possibility that Jedi can turn bad... "Ezra turning to the Dark Side was a dangerous possibility." That makes sense, but oh, so disappointing. I wanted a redemption similar to Vader/Anakin's spirit-appearance at the end of episode VI with Yoda and Obi-Wan.

Comment: @CanadianGirlScout In the movies, Yoda said that once you turn to the Dark Side, you're pretty much doomed. I would rather have Vader's redemption be special and uncommon.